# Can not include Behavior

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior

I implement some code,but i can not resolve Behavior class. 
I click on this class, but VS 2013 propose create class "Behavoir", not some assembly.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you have the french version of Visual Studio... ;-)

Comment: No- it is English version)) @Farhad Jabiyev set correct answer:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` to use the `Behavior` class.

You can download it from the [Nuget Package Manager](http://nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interctivity.WPF.v4.0/1.0.3).